# Accumalate column through pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have multiple tab delimited files, all having same entries. I intend to read each file choose first column as index. My final table will have first column as index mapped against last column from all the files. For this, I wrote a pandas code but not a great ones. Is there an alternate way to do this ?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("FB_test.tsv",sep='\t')
df1_idx = df1.set_index('target_id')
df1_idx.drop(df1_idx[['length','eff_length','est_counts']],inplace=True, axis=1)
print(df1_idx)
df2 = pd.read_csv("Myc_test.tsv",sep='\t')
df2_idx = df2.set_index('target_id')
df2_idx.drop(df2_idx[['length','eff_length','est_counts']],inplace=True, axis=1)
print(df2_idx)
frames = [df1_idx, df2_idx]
results = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
results
```

The output it generated was,

```
           tpm
target_id     
A            0
B            0
C            0
D            0
E            0
           tpm
target_id     
A            1
B            1
C            1
D            1
E            1
Out[18]:
target_id   tpm  tpm    
A   0   1
B   0   1
C   0   1
D   0   1
E   0   1
```

How to loop it so that, I read each file and achieve this same output ?

Thanks,
AP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use parameters `index_col` and `usecols` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with `list comprehension`. But get duplicates columns names (so is problem for selecting), so better is add parameter `keys` to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) - after converting `Multiindex` get nice unique column names:

```
files = ["FB_test.tsv", "Myc_test.tsv"]
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f,sep='\t', index_col=['target_id'], usecols=['target_id','tpm']) 
      for f in files]
results = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=('a','b'))
results.columns = results.columns.map('_'.join)
results = results.reset_index()
print (results)
  target_id  a_tpm  b_tpm
0         A      0      1
1         B      0      1
2         C      0      1
3         D      0      1
4         E      0      1
```

Answer (score 1):

To clean the code and use a looping mechanism, you can put both your file names and the columns you are dropping in two separate lists, and then use list comprehension on the file names to import each dataset. Subsequently, you concatenate the output of the list comprehension into one dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd


drop_cols = ['length','eff_length','est_counts']
filenames = ["FB_test.tsv", "Myc_test.tsv"]
results = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(filename,sep='\t').set_index('target_id').drop(drop_cols, axis=1) for filename in filenames], axis=1)
```

I hope this helps.